# Can't reproduce working C bitwise encoding function in Python

Tags: python, security, python-2.7, encoding, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse engineering a proprietary network protocol that generates a (static) one-time pad on launch and then uses that to encode/decode each packet it sends/receives.  It uses the one-time pad in a series of complex XORs, shifts, and multiplications.

I have produced the following C code after walking through the decoding function in the program with IDA.  This function encodes/decodes the data perfectly:

```
void encodeData(char *buf)
{
    int i;
    size_t bufLen = *(unsigned short *)buf;
    unsigned long entropy = *((unsigned long *)buf + 2);
    int xorKey = 9 * (entropy ^ ((entropy ^ 0x3D0000) >> 16));
    unsigned short baseByteTableIndex = (60205 * (xorKey ^ (xorKey >> 4)) ^ (668265261 * (xorKey ^ (xorKey >> 4)) >> 15)) & 0x7FFF;

    //Skip first 24 bytes, as that is the header
    for (i = 24; i <= (signed int)bufLen; i++)
        buf[i] ^= byteTable[((unsigned short)i + baseByteTableIndex) & 2047];
}
```

Now I want to try my hand at making a Peach fuzzer for this protocol.  Since I'll need a custom Python fixup to do the encoding/decoding prior to doing the fuzzing, I need to port this C code to Python.

I've made the following Python function but haven't had any luck with it decoding the packets it receives.

```
def encodeData(buf):
    newBuf = bytearray(buf)
    bufLen = unpack('H', buf[:2])
    entropy = unpack('I', buf[2:6])
    xorKey = 9 * (entropy[0] ^ ((entropy[0] ^ 0x3D0000) >> 16))
    baseByteTableIndex = (60205 * (xorKey ^ (xorKey >> 4)) ^ (668265261 * (xorKey ^ (xorKey >> 4)) >> 15)) & 0x7FFF;
    #Skip first 24 bytes, since that is header data
    for i in range(24,bufLen[0]):
        newBuf[i] = xorPad[(i + baseByteTableIndex) & 2047]
    return str(newBuf)
```

I've tried with and without using `array()` or `pack()`/`unpack()` on various variables to force them to be the right size for the bitwise operations, but I must be missing something, because I can't get the Python code to work as the C code does.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

In case it would help you to try this locally, here is the one-time pad generating function:

```
def buildXorPad():
    global xorPad
    xorKey = array('H', [0xACE1])
    for i in range(0, 2048):
        xorKey[0] = -(xorKey[0] & 1) & 0xB400 ^ (xorKey[0] >> 1)
        xorPad = xorPad + pack('B',xorKey[0] & 0xFF)
```

And here is the hex-encoded original (encoded) and decoded packet.

Original: `20000108fcf3d71d98590000010000000000000000000000a992e0ee2525a5e5`

Decoded: `20000108fcf3d71d98590000010000000000000000000000ae91e1ee25252525`

## Solution

It turns out that my problem didn't have much to do with the difference between C and Python types, but rather some simple programming mistakes.

```
def encodeData(buf):
    newBuf = bytearray(buf)
    bufLen = unpack('H', buf[:2])
    entropy = unpack('I', buf[8:12])
    xorKey = 9 * (entropy[0] ^ ((entropy[0] ^ 0x3D0000) >> 16))
    baseByteTableIndex = (60205 * (xorKey ^ (xorKey >> 4)) ^ (668265261 * (xorKey ^ (xorKey >> 4)) >> 15)) & 0x7FFF;
    #Skip first 24 bytes, since that is header data
    for i in range(24,bufLen[0]):
        padIndex = (i + baseByteTableIndex) & 2047
        newBuf[i] ^= unpack('B',xorPad[padIndex])[0]
    return str(newBuf)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: The decoded data is almost identical to the original data - is that right?

Comment: Yes, I should have added more comments to the code.  The first 24 bytes are the header, which is not encoded.  I chose this packet in particular because the "payload" minus the header is only 8 bytes long, and I know the last 4 bytes should be 0x25252525 when decoded.

Comment: The rightshifts may be behaving differently in C and python. I'd start by masking all calculations to the right bitlength and figuring out if you need a logical or arithmetic shift and make it explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of C:

```
unsigned long entropy = *((unsigned long *)buf + 2);
```

should translate to

```
entropy = unpack('I', buf[8:12])
```

because `buf` is cast to an unsigned long first before adding 2 to the address, which adds the size of 2 unsigned longs to it, not 2 bytes (assuming an unsigned long is 4 bytes in size).

Also:

```
newBuf[i] = xorPad[(i + baseByteTableIndex) & 2047]
```

should be

```
newBuf[i] ^= xorPad[(i + baseByteTableIndex) & 2047]
```

to match the C, otherwise the output isn't actually based on the contents of the buffer.

Comment: Ok you're onto something here.  I can't believe I missed that I was grabbing the wrong part of the packet for the entropy value!  I even had a 010 Editor template that showed where it was, but apparently ignored it.  The problem is that it still doesn't work.  It might be an endian-ness issue, and I'll try to troubleshoot that in the morning.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I guess it was just some simple programming mistakes rather than encoding/type issues.  I'll need to be more careful!  I posted the final encoding function in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Python integers don't overflow - they are automatically promoted to arbitrary precision when they exceed `sys.maxint` (or `-sys.maxint-1`).

```
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> sys.maxint + 1
9223372036854775808L
```

Using `array` and/or `unpack` does not seem to make a difference (as you discovered)

```
>>> array('H', [1])[0] + sys.maxint
9223372036854775808L
>>> unpack('H', '\x01\x00')[0] + sys.maxint
9223372036854775808L
```

To truncate your numbers, you'll have to simulate overflow by manually ANDing with an appropriate bitmask whenever you're increasing the size of the variable.

Comment: By XORing do you mean ANDing?  I've tried ANDing with a bitmask as well, but I'll try again and make sure I catch every case that needs to be masked off.

Comment: @k0ss, yes sorry I'll fix the post

Comment: Upvoted because although I had already tried this, it's a good suggestion for someone who needs to artificially limit the size of a variable.